# How to parse token beginning with "."

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am using pyparsing to parse an assembly language.  In this language, directives begin with a "." but I can't seem to get it to parse correctly.  Is there something special about the period character?  Can you tell me what is wrong with the following code?

```
import pyparsing as pp

directive="."+pp.OneOrMore(pp.alphas)
test=[
    r".ORG",
    r".RB",
    r".rm"]

for t in test:
    print t
    print pp.Optional(directive).parseString(t)
```

Comment: What's the desired output? You want it to print `['.', 'ORG']` for the first one?

Comment: yes.  But I don't get any token returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be anything special about `.`, and it works fine with other elements. Here is an example of a grammar consisting of words beginning with `.`:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, Literal

example = Literal('.') + Word(alphas)
```

`example.parseString(...)` indeed parses only words beginning with `.`.

Comment: OK-what you are doing works-looks like it is my use of OneOrMore is the problem.

Comment: Yes, `OneOrMore` is the problem here. `alphas` is a string of all alphabetic characters. `OneOrMore("abc")` will match "abc", "abcabc", "abcabcabc", etc., but not "aaa" or "bac". If you want a word group of one or more of these, build them with a `Word` class.  In fact, Word supports a two-argument form where you can specify one string of characters for valid leading characters, and a second string of valid body characters.  So you could actually just define directive as `Word('.', alphas)`